# In Javascript, why does var outside of loop get updated from var inside?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

This code provides the correct output, but I would think that `var total` outside of the loop would have it's own space in memory and the one inside the loop would have its own also. I would also think that the line inside the loop would update itself and not the one on top, but it seems like it updates the top one. Does it have something to do with hoisting and that these two variables are actually the same? If so, is the `var total` inside the loop really just `total`?

```js
var numbers = [10, 15, 20, 35];
var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  var total = total + numbers[i];
}

console.log(total);
```

Comment: [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is not block-scoped like `let` or `const`.

Comment: [MDN Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). `var` is `function scope` while `let` and `const` are `block scope`, so both `total` variables belong to the same scope in this case which means it is just being redeclared (`let` and `const` cannot be redeclared unlike `var`)

Comment: @mykaf Correct. That doesn't explain the mechanism by which this is working correctly.

Comment: Each time through the loop, a new variable called `total` is set to the old variable called `total` + `numbers[i]`. Each iteration creates a new variable that uses the old variable of the same name.

Comment: @Danny If it's being redeclared, then there is only one `total` variable?

Comment: @tazboy Yes, with `let` and `const` you will get the expected behavior since each `total` would have its own scope.